# PHP: code to create mysql table with default value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table and set default values at the same time. Is it possible? When I create a table without default values, it is working fine. But when I try to add default values, it does not work. Please point out the error.

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE test 
    (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    test_id INT,
    pwd VARCHAR(50),
    cost FLOAT(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'on',
    code INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    scene VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0,0,0,0,0'
    ) TYPE=innoDB");
```

Comment: nothng wrong in the query

Comment: Probably table with same name "test" already exists. Try to add at the start of query sentence "drop table if exists test;"

Comment: Ran the query fine on my DB, I agree with Alexander.  A bit of a tip:  scene looks like a multivalued attribute.  You should consider making a second table using the id as a foreign key to assign multivalued attributes rather than storing them with commas.

Comment: do not use single quotes with integer and float fields